# Angular - How to change url for child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component, let's say `/settings`, and I have couple child components `/comp1` or `comp2` in here. I can switch between them without going out from `settings`. While I am switching between these child components, my url `/settings` stays the same. I am using **ngIf** to change components, not navigating to them, because I want to open them in **Settings Component**. How can I change url like this: `/settings/comp1` or `/settings/comp2`

Comment: You have to set up the correct routing, how are you doing things now?

Answer (score 0):

Your routing should be something like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'settings',
    children: [
      { path: 'comp1', component: Component1 },
      { path: 'comp2', component: Component2 },
    ],
    component: SettingsComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: I am opening those child components in settings component. I tried this, but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I've edited my question. Please look again.

Comment: Child component doesn't open.